# How do I get groups__name on a line in the Django user model query?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I want get groups__name in a line at `User.objects.values('id', 'username', 'groups__name')`

But I get example:

```
{'groups__name': None, 'id': 1, 'username': 'admin'},
{'groups__name': 'Manager', 'id': 2, 'username': 'test'},
{'groups__name': 'Personal', 'id': 2, 'username': 'test'}
```

I want query like this example:

```
{'id': 1, 'groups__name': None, 'username': 'admin'},
{'id': 2, 'groups__name': ('Manager', 'Personal'), 'username': 'test'}
```

I use django 1.11

Comment: You are missing a single quote after "groups__name" in the first line, is that in your code as well?

Comment: No. I wrote it wrong here. Sorry. I will edit.

Comment: in single query you can not do it

Comment: @BearBrown On the contrary, it is possible by one query.

Comment: @hynekcer i mean to get the result by `query set` only, but by query plus python yes you are right )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct, but the results must be also manipulate in Python thereafter to get all related names in one row as tuples. The function [**`itretools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) expects that an iterable parameter is sorted by the `key` function (i.e. extracted User objects items without items related to Group).

```
from itertools import groupby

qs = (User.objects.values('id', 'username', 'groups__name')
      .order_by('username', 'id', 'groups__name')
      )
qs_list = []

for key, gr in groupby(qs, key=lambda x:
                       tuple((k, v) for k, v in x.items() if k != 'groups__name')):
    groups__name  = tuple(x['groups__name'] for x in gr if x['groups__name'] is not None)
    qs_list.append(dict(key + (('groups__name', groups__name or None),)))
```

Footnotes:
The primary key is not important in `order by`, but I added it because you didn't write anything about the model. I expected `django.contrib.auth.models` or something with ManyToMany relationship between User and Group, and attribute `Group.name.null == False`, otherwise an additional non null field (like `pk`) must be used also to distinguish a null value from missing related objects.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I will always use this idea.